# Pytest: collecting 0 items even after following the conventions

Tags: pytest

I created a test module by following all the conventions, but when I run the test, I get the following message:
collecting 0 items

Here's my directory hierarchy:
integration_tests (Directory)-> tests (Directory)-> test_integration_use_cases.py (python file)

And this is the content of the file:

```
import pytest
from some_tests.integration_tests.backbone.SomeIntegrationTestBase import SomeIntegrationTestBase

class TestSomeIntegration(SomeIntegrationTestBase):

    @pytest.mark.p1
    def test_some_integration_use_cases(self):
        print("**** Executing integration tests ****")
        result = self.execute_test(4)
        assert (True == result)
```

when I run the following command:
pytest test_integration_use_cases.py
I see the following result without any errors:
collecting 0 items

FYI: I am running this on a development machine (Like vagrant)

Comment: Do you run the command `pytest test_integration_use_cases.py` in the directory `tests`? Because with such a command `pytest` expects the file in the current directory.

Comment: No... I ran the command from the directory where the test is present.

Comment: Run following command "pytest -vv test_integration_use_cases.py" and copy output here. Does pytest stop working?

Answer (score 0):

so I had the same problem as you have even after following all the recommended conventions. My application structure was as follows;

```
Application
-- API
   app.py
-- docs
-- venv
-- tests
   -- unit_test
      test_factory
      ...
...
```

I, however, resolved the issue by moving the tests directory under the API package so that my application structure looked as below;

```
Application
-- API
   app.py
   -- tests
      -- unit_test
         test_factory
         ...    
-- docs
-- venv
...
```

Although **pytest** is supposed to auto-discover the tests, it seems to do that if they are placed in the application root. Check out the [pytest for flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/)

I also found [this resource](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html) helpful.